# Added id to div, now form field is not full width

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

I've got a form that dynamically displays one of three followup fields, depending on a previous question. This is the selector question and the dynamically appearing field:

```
 <!-- Selector -->
        <div id="selector" class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="selector">Booking Type</label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="radio">
            <label for="selector">
              <input name="selector" id="selector" value="Customer/Jobsite" onclick="show1();" type="radio">Customer/Jobsite</label>
            </div>
                <div class="radio">
            <label for="selector">
              <input name="selector" id="selector" value="Absence" onclick="show2();" type="radio">Absence</label>
            </div>
                <div class="radio">
            <label for="selector">
              <input name="selector" id="selector" value="Custom" onclick="show3();" type="radio">Custom</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Result Jobsite -->
        <div id="ResultJobsite" class="form-group" style="display:none;">
            <div class="form-row">
          <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="Result">Customer/Jobsite</label>
          <div class="col-md-12" class="form-group">
            <select id="ResultJobsite" name="ResultJobsite" class="form-control select2_field">
                <option value=""></option>
            @foreach (App\Models\Customer::all()->sortby('Customer') as $row)
                <option <?php if ("{{ $row->Customer }}" == "{{ $entry->Result }}") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="{{ $row->Customer }}">{{ $row->Customer }}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the javascript that controls it's appearance:

```
 function show1(){
          document.getElementById('ResultJobsite').style.display ='block';
          document.getElementById('ResultAbsence').style.display ='none';
          document.getElementById('ResultLongform').style.display ='none';
          document.getElementById('ResultShortform').style.display ='none';
        }
        function show2(){
          document.getElementById('ResultJobsite').style.display ='none';
          document.getElementById('ResultAbsence').style.display ='block';
          document.getElementById('ResultLongform').style.display ='none';
          document.getElementById('ResultShortform').style.display ='none';
        }
        function show3(){
          document.getElementById('ResultJobsite').style.display ='none';
          document.getElementById('ResultAbsence').style.display ='none';
          document.getElementById('ResultLongform').style.display ='block';
          document.getElementById('ResultShortform').style.display ='block';
        }
```

Essentially, adding id="ResultJobsite" to the field allows it to show/hide dynamically as needed, but it no longer displays the field full width as the rest are. Removing id="ResultJobsite" restores it to its full width.

What's happening here?

Comment: first of all you gave same id at `<div>` and `<section>`. please correct it.

Comment: If you open the developer console (usually F12) and go through the DOM to the element you want and check the computed properties you can check why it's different.

Answer (score 0):

Add class form-control to those input fileds to get full width.